# Where can I lookup what language corresponds to a IANA language tag?

Tags: standards

As far as I understand language tags get validated by IANA registration of being proper standard compliant tags. 
If I have a given tag like "mn-mong" how do I go about looking up the meaning of the tag in the registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look these up at IANA's own site:

- https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-tags/language-tags.xhtml#language-tags-1

> In "Tags for the Identification of Languages" [BCP47] [RFC3066] there
>   is a provision for listing unique "tags" or names for languages and
>   variants of languages.  This document summaries the list of assigned
>   language tags.